# Lein clean and re-download dependencies

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm working on setting up some password protected dependency repositories. I'd like to clear all dependency packages and re-download to make sure the package restore is working correctly.

How should I clear the lein package cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no edge cases by additional plugins `rm -rf ~/.m2/repository` is the **brute force** version -- this removes **all**
deps ever downloaded by Leiningen (and also Maven and maybe others).

If you want to be very specific for a certain project, you can get the
list of all actual files by `lein cp` (Warning: this also contains your
source files!  So you usually want the ones in `~/.m2/repository`.  Of
course you use version control and have backups and therefor no problem
here...).  From the list of `lein cp` you would at least want to remove
the `dirname` portion to kill the version, or go up two for the whole
artifact.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answer, you can list the individual directories under `~/.m2`.  For example:

```
~/expr/demo > d ~/.m2/repository/cl[jo]*
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Jan  5  2017 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-aws-s3/
drwxr-xr-x  5 alan alan 4096 Nov  4 21:26 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-commons/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Mar 30  2018 /home/alan/.m2/repository/cljfmt/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Nov 15  2017 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-http/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Nov 15  2017 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-http-lite/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Sep 17  2018 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-jdbcutil/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Nov 18  2017 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-jgit/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Sep 17  2018 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-liquibase/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Jun 19  2018 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-logging-config/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Sep 17  2018 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-miscutil/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Apr 25  2020 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-python/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Apr  1  2018 /home/alan/.m2/repository/cljs-ajax/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Mar 13  2018 /home/alan/.m2/repository/cljsbuild/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Apr 20  2019 /home/alan/.m2/repository/cljs-commons/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Sep 17  2018 /home/alan/.m2/repository/cljs-http/
drwxr-xr-x 17 alan alan 4096 Jan 28 10:25 /home/alan/.m2/repository/cljsjs/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Dec 18  2019 /home/alan/.m2/repository/cljs-log/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Jan 25  2017 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-stacktrace/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Mar 30  2018 /home/alan/.m2/repository/cljs-tooling/
drwxr-xr-x  4 alan alan 4096 Mar 25  2019 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-time/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Jan  5  2017 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-tuple/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Nov 18  2017 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clj-yaml/
drwxr-xr-x  4 alan alan 4096 Jul 19  2018 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clojure/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Jan  5  2017 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clojure-complete/
drwxr-xr-x  3 alan alan 4096 Jan  5  2017 /home/alan/.m2/repository/clojure-csv/
```

You can then use `rm -rf` on a specific subset that you wish to test (i.e. force re-download).